# Riemann Integral and continuous functions

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

I wish to find all functions $f$ on $[0,1]$ such that $f$ is continuous on $[0,1]$ and
$$\int_0^x f(t)\ dt = \int_x^1 f(t)\ dt$$
for every $x$ in $(0,1)$. I think I need to apply the concept of Riemann integral here but I have no clue how. Could anyone help?

Comment: Differentiate both sides.

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^x f(t)\,dt &= -\int_1^x f(t)\,dt \\
\frac{d}{dx} \int_0^x f(t) \, dt &= -\frac{d}{dx} \int_1^x f(t) \, dt \\
f(x) &= -f(x) \\
\end{align}$$

So how about $f(x)=0$? Dividing both sides of the equation for any $f(x)\neq0$ gives $1=-1$.

Comment: Thanks for the help! So f=0 is a possible function too right but then what's with the 1 = -1 contradiction?

Comment: @Homaniac I’m trying to explore whether there are functions *other than* $f(x)=0$ that are also solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Add $\int_{0}^{x}f(t)dt$ at both sides of the equation You get:
$$2\int_{0}^{x}f(t)dt=\int_{0}^{1}f(t)dt$$.
Differentiate both sides, and get:
$$2f(x)=0$$ 
for every $x \in [0,1]$.